# binary array, interview questions

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-data

I have been practicing some java interview coding questions and I came across this question below.

> You are given an integer array with N elements: d[0], d[1], ... d[N -
>   1].  You can perform AT MOST one move on the array: choose any two
>   integers [L, R], and flip all the elements between (and including) the
>   L-th and R-th bits. L and R represent the left-most and right-most
>   index of the bits marking the boundaries of the segment which you have
>   decided to flip.
>
> What is the maximum number of '1'-bits (indicated by S) which you can
>   obtain in the final bit-string?
>
> 'Flipping' a bit means, that a 0 is transformed to a 1 and a 1 is
>   transformed to a 0 (0->1,1->0).  Input Format  An integer N  Next line
>   contains the N bits, separated by spaces: d[0] d[1] ... d[N - 1]

In the part below, the question is explained with an example and I am not able to understand the results of the example. The problem here is I should understand the question first and then I can try solving for the problem.

> Solution given:
>
> Output:  S
>
> Constraints:  1 <= N <= 100000  d[i] can only be 0 or 1  0 <= L <= R <
>   n
>
> Sample Input:  8  1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
>
> Sample Output:  6
>
> Explanation:
>
> We can get a maximum of 6 ones in the given binary array by performing
>   either of the following operations:  Flip [1, 5] ==> 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0

I dont get it how the sample output is 6 and how we can get a maximum of 6 ones in the given binary array.

Can someone please help in my understanding. I know its something really simple but somehow I dont get it.

thanks !

Comment: in 15yrs I've never needed to do any bitwise manipulation at work

Comment: While bitwise manipulation might not be needed in day to day work, I think its a solid concept to understand. I use it often but regardless being able to "figure it out on paper" is a good skill to have IMO

Comment: Why does the Sample Input have an 8? Is that the number of bits?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that it's the length of the bitstring. The output is the number of bits set to 1.

Comment: The version of the source question [here](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=6262507668766720) describes `d` as a *binary* array, which is crucially different from an *integer* array, and makes a whole lot more sense.

Comment: How is this a Java question, btw?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I assumed its the size

Comment: It appears, you have to identify a consecutive index range over the bit vector so that when all bits within it are flipped, the resulting total number of ones is maximized. Note that this range need not be unique: `[1,7]` would be another answer producing a *different* output with 6 bits set: `1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start here:

> In the part below, the question is explained with an example and I am not able to understand the results of the example. The problem here is I should understand the question first and then I can try solving for the problem.

You are trying to apply a single bit-shift operation across a contiguous range, where your goal is to maximize the number of 1's in the array.

Looking at our Sample input of size 8

```
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

We notice there are 5 0's. To super summarize my thought process, the real problem is to identify a range that bit flipping will net you the biggest positive change, in other words, "Find a range that has the most 0's and the least 1's"

We look at the sample input and see bit 0 is a 1, so we already exclude that. Bit 1 and 2 are 0's, which compels us to have this be in our range. Bit 3 is a 1, but the next two bits, bit 4 and 5 are zeroes, which means including bits 3, 4 and 5 will have a net gain. Looking at bits 6 and 7, they "cancel each other out", meaning including them or excluding them doesn't matter.

So to wrap that up, our range starts at bit 1 and ends with bit 5 (inclusively).

After the flipping, we're left with

```
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

Or 6 1's, which is the sample output

Feel free leave any further questions. This approach was a "human approach" that we could do with such a small input size. Writing an algorithm to find the best range would have many more steps after running through a small sample size by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about arrays for moment, you have binary number:

```
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

you task is to find left and right indexes, such as:

```
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
  ^       ^
  left    right
```

when you invert every bit between left/right and calculate number of ones (1) in final number/array, find combination of left/right indexes with maximal number of 1s

in this particular example if we take left 1, right 5, final array will be

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 (indexes)
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 (original array)
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 (I've inverted, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th)
```

now, how we can calculate it. first method usually is brute force, try all possible combinations of left/right and find max:

```
public static void main(final String s[]) {
    final int[] d = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0};
    int max = getOnes(d);
    for (int left = 0; left < (d.length - 1); left++) {
        for (int right = (left + 1); right < d.length; right++) {
            invert(d, left, right); // flip bits
            max = Math.max(max, getOnes(d));
            invert(d, left, right); // reverse flipping
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
}

static int getOnes(final int[] d) {
    int cnt = 0;
    for (final int i : d) cnt += i;
    return cnt;
}

static void invert(final int[] d, final int left, final int right) {
    for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) d[i] = (1 - d[i]);
}
```

next step is to optimize this solution, here are several hints:

1. left index is either 0 or it is index of first zero in sequence
2. right index is either array length-1 or last zero of sequence
3. you don't need to actually flip bits in array to calculate number of 1s, just calculate 0s
4. you don't need to re-calculate this number from scratch, you can just adjust it